Save folder of workbooks to individual PDFs
I had the macro below which previously would go to the folder and open each workbook and save it as a PDF; however, it seems now it opens the file and stops running the macro.
Path is defined and works, the issue is after it run the line for Workbooks.Open it stops there.
Sub PrintFolderToPDF()
'Functions
    Dim wbktoExport As Workbook
    Dim strSourceExcelLocation As String
    
    DefineVars
    TurnOffFunctions
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo FireExit

    strSourceExcelLocation = Path & "\"

    'Search all Excel files in the directory with .xlsx extensions
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\" & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        'Open the workbook
'This is last line before it stops without an error
        Set wbktoExport = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileName, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False) '
        


        'Export all sheets as single PDF
         Export_Excel_as_PDF (wbktoExport)

        'Get next workbook
        FileName = Dir

        'Close Excel workbook without making changes
        wbktoExport.Close False
    Loop

FireExit:
    TurnOnFunctions
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Temporarily disable error handling to better determine what line throws the error. Side note: Export_Excel_as_PDF (wbktoExport) shouldn't have any parentheses.

Hi @bigben seems the parenthesis was the issue, removed it and now seems to be operating as expected. Odd thing is this was running not too long ago as it was. Thank you
